# What does "a single total order" mean in std::notify_one()?

Tags: c++

I have read [Concurrency: Atomic and volatile in C++11 memory model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819095/concurrency-atomic-and-volatile-in-c11-memory-model) and [How std::memory_order_seq_cst works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963559/how-stdmemory-order-seq-cst-works), it doesn't help much and answer my question directly.

---

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one:

> The effects of `notify_one()`/`notify_all()` and each of the three atomic
>   parts of `wait()`/`wait_for()`/`wait_until()` (unlock+wait, wakeup, and
>   lock) **take place in a single total order** that can be viewed as
>   modification order of an atomic variable: the order is specific to
>   this individual condition_variable. This makes it impossible for
>   `notify_one()` to, for example, be delayed and unblock a thread that
>   started waiting just after the call to `notify_one()` was made.

What does it mean by saying "take place in a single total order"? How is this related to the next sentence "This makes it impossible ..... was made."? (It seems that it's telling a cause and effect).

I read it word by word more than 10 times and don't understand what it's saying.. Definition of "total order" from Wikipedia can't help much.

Comment: I read the last sentence as: If one thread called `notify_one()`, then the thread which is woken up started it's waiting before `notify_one()` was called. (It's impossible that a thread is considered which started waiting after.) At this point, there is granted a certain determinism, that normally isn't between threads (without any kind of locking/synchronization).

Comment: Why is this duplicate ..? I took a glance at those two questions and did not find an direct answer.

Answer (score 3):

> What does it mean by saying "take place in a single total order"?

It means that every thread sees same sequence of operations. As an example, using multiple non-atomic variables, thread C can see the changes to `int a` caused by thread A, before it sees changes to `int b` caused by thread B, while thread D sees those of B before A. There are multiple incompatible timelines of which events occur before others, potentially every thread disagreeing with another. Without synchronisation mechanisms (like `std::condition_variable`) it can be impossible to prevent unwanted system behaviours.

A *total order* means that every element can be compared to every other element (contrast a partial order, where some pairs of elements are incomparable). In this case, there exists a timeline of events. It is *single* in that all threads agree on it.

> How is this related to the next sentence "This makes it impossible for `notify_one()` to, for example, be delayed and unblock a thread that started waiting just after the call to `notify_one()` was made."?

Because all threads agree on the order that things happen, you can't anywhere observing an effect preceding it's cause.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I would however be keen on reading more about this topic. Do you have any reference to share?