# Understanding memory_order_seq_cst in java

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers

Most blogsites like [this](https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-06/cpp-memory-order/#:%7E:text=Memory%20Order%20in%20C%2B%2B%201%201.%20Atomic%20variables,Modification%20orders%20...%203%203.%20Memory%20order%20) one for example when explaining about memory_order_seq_cst always talks about this example

```
std::atomic<bool> x{false}, y{false};
std::atomic<int> z{0};

void thread1() {
 x.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // (1)
}

void thread2() {
 y.store(true, std::memory_order_seq_cst); // (2)
}


void read_x_then_y() {
    while (!x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)); // (3)
    if (y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) ++z; // (4)
}

void read_y_then_x() {
    while (!y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)); // (5)
    if (x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) ++z; // (6)
}

int main() 
{
 std::thread a(thread1), b(thread2), c(read_x_then_y), d(read_y_then_x);
 a.join(), b.join(), c.join(), d.join();
 assert(z.load() != 0); // (7)
}
```

When translating this into java code i get this

```
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
 {
  AtomicBoolean 
  x=new AtomicBoolean(false),
  y=new AtomicBoolean(false);
  AtomicInteger z=new AtomicInteger(0);
  
  while(true)
  {
   z.set(0);
   
   Thread t1=new Thread(()->x.set(true));
   
   Thread t2=new Thread(()->y.set(true));
   
   Thread t3=new Thread(()->
   {
    while(!x.get()){}
    if(y.get()){z.incrementAndGet();}
   });
   
   Thread t4=new Thread(()->
   {
    while(!y.get()){}
    if(x.get()){z.incrementAndGet();}
   });
   
   t1.start();
   t2.start();
   t3.start();
   t4.start();
   
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
   t3.join();
   t4.join();
   
   assert(z.get()!=0);
  }
 }
```

The whileloop is used to generate infinite test cases to see if the assert fails at any point and the [set()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#set(int)) from the documentation has similar memory effects to [setVolatile()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#setVolatile(java.lang.Object...)) which if we read from the API note has memory effects like memory_order_seq_cst

This example works but i fell is deceptive because it does not explain how memory_order_seq_cst ensures the assertion is always true. The program itself appears to be written in such a way that regardless of what memory_order method you use to load/store

```
set(),setPlain(),setOpaque(),setRelease()
get(),getPlain(),getOpaque(),getAquire()
```

the assertion always succeeds and it never fails so how exactly does memory_order_seq  play a unique role in this example?

Comment: This is the IRIW litmus test.  Unless you tested on a recent PowerPC server, all threads will agree on the order of stores, even if the stores are `relaxed` and the loads are just `acquire`.  ISO C++ doesn't guarantee it without `seq_cst`, but it also doesn't guarantee that every allowed ordering actually will be observed in practice.  Especially ones the hardware you choose doesn't do naturally.  (The loads do need to be `acquire` so it doesn't fail because of local load-load reordering on the readers, actually observing the global order of store visibility)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see)  Also [Acquire/release semantics with 4 threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48383867)  And comments on [Still can't get a true root cause explanation on IRIW scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69003544)

Comment: If you were testing this on x86 hardware, [What does it mean that "two store are seen in a consistent order by other processors"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63912669) is a duplicate that explains why you can't observe IRIW reordering on that system.